# How to remove names from the non-empty namespaces they belong to?

Tags: xslt

I want to transform an input xml file using xslt to change the name of a particular element which can appear at different places of the xml tree.

I have an xml like the following,

```
 <catalog>
 <cd>
  <ost:title>Empire Burlesque</ost:title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>
     <ost:name>Columbia<ost:name>
  </company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to remove all the 'ost:' prefix from all the elements and keep everything else as it is using xslt. An example code will be appreciated.

Comment: Indent 4 spaces or use the 101010 button to enter code.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Hello, Yes we have the name space for ost. Actually we want to revert the xml to a previous version which didnt support this ost name space. Thanks for the reply

Comment: It's nice that *you* have it, but... what about *us*?

Comment: I am sorry, would you please elaborate a bit more about what you need?

Comment: We need the namespace for `ost`.

Comment: @Hasif, first, please register; you're creating new accounts accidentally which I don't think you want to do.  Second, while you do not have enough reputation to create comments in general, you can leave comments on answers here.  So, when responding to an answer, hit the "add comment" link under the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a very general transformation that puts elements and attributes belonging to a given set of namespaces, in no namespace. It also removes all namespace nodes for these namespaces. The set of namespaces can be specified globally (or as a parameter).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you don't seem to have other namespaces than the one you want to remove. So, here is an example of an XSLT stylesheet, which removes *all* namespaces from elements (not just your `ost:`).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template: copy everything as is... -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ... except for elements, 
       create a similarly named element without a namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses the [identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) to copy everything as-is, but overrides that for elements to create an element with the same local name, but no namespace.

If you want to just remove your `ost:` namespace, you can include the namespace declaration for that namespace, and change the latter template to match `ost:*`.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation is most general. It removes all elements and attributes from namespaces that are specified within a global parameter. It also removes all namespace nodes that are one of those namespaces**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:delNs>
   <ns>some:namespace1</ns>
   <ns>some:namespace3</ns>
 </my:delNs>

 <xsl:variable name="vdelNS"
  select="document('')/*/my:delNs/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.=$vdelNS)]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template priority="10" match=
 "*[namespace-uri()=document('')/*/my:delNs/*]">

  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.=$vdelNS)]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "@*[namespace-uri()=document('')/*/my:delNs/*]">
   <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided, but corrected to be well-formed and extended to contain 3 namespaces and elements and attributes in them):

```
 <catalog xmlns:ost="some:namespace1"
  xmlns:x="some:namespace2"
  xmlns:y="some:namespace3">
 <cd>
  <ost:title>Empire Burlesque</ost:title>
  <y:artist>Bob Dylan</y:artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company ost:type="big">
     <ost:name>Columbia</ost:name>
  </company>
  <x:price>10.90</x:price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<catalog xmlns:x="some:namespace2">
   <cd>
      <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
      <company type="big">
         <name>Columbia</name>
      </company>
      <x:price>10.90</x:price>
      <year>1985</year>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The first two templates are almost equivalent to the identity rule, but they do not copy namespace nodes for the namespaces specified in** `<my:delNs>`.
2. **The last two templates are for all elements and attributes that belong to a namespace listed under** `<my:delNs>`. Only in these two templates names are actually changed to only local names.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. I think I have an interesting topic to discuss. I can be found on the Google's mail using my Wordpress blog userid.